# BigDecimal JPA precision lost issue

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

In java application I use:

- Oracle database 11g
- JPA with standard jEE implementation as
  persistence layer (open jpa)
- Wildfly application server

In JPA entity I defined BigDecimal numeric value:

```
@Column(name = "MON_AMT", precision=18, scale=2)
private BigDecimal moneyAmount;

public void setMoneyAmount(BigDecimal moneyAmount){
    this.moneyAmount = moneyAmount;
}

public BigDecimal getMoneyAmount(){
    return moneyAmount;
}
```

In database this column is defined as NUMBER(18,2), so the precision is 18 and the scale is 2.

When I try to save such example value: 1234567890123456.89, it's probably incorrectly mapped from database to BigDecimal value by JPA at persistence layer. Consequently I obtain number: 1234567890123457 (number is rounded up) while reading back from db.

The number has been correctly sent from UI layer and correctly stored in database (SQL query returned proper value 1234567890123456.89).

What's more interesting problem does not exist for smaller numbers (e.g 4567.89)

I tried to resolve problem by adding parameters scale and precision to JPA @Column annotation as you can see above, but without expected results.

The issue is very uncomfortable and potentially can cause a disaster, because stored values are money values.

Do you have any ideas what can be a reason of such symptoms?

Comment: I found a [similar stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956050/bigdecimal-precision-not-persisted-with-jpa-annotations).  In that question, it looked like the problem was that JPA was actually trying to reduce the precision or scale of the column which the database did not like since that table already had existing data.  Could that be what's happening here?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately my case is different - I have already created table and column with correct precision. In my case also value is correctly persisted in database - the problem occurs while retrieving data.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think that the meaning of "precision" and "scale" is little bit different in Oracle and Java.

Comment: The JPA definition of precision and scale map directly on to what RDBMS uses. If this operation doesn't work then raise it as a bug against your JPA provider.

Comment: Thank you for all replies. It was a problem with serialization to json at app services layer.

Comment: @Viper, then please delete the question or change it accordingly. The cause was not Hibernate.